# how to take a screenshot by a locator and then compare with the other locator with the screenshot using appium with webdriverio

Tags: appium, webdriver-io

how to take a screenshot by a locator and then compare with the other locator with the screenshot(and compare those two images) using appium with webdriverio. I tried looking at a tutorial but not able to find anything that works

Comment: which language you are using?

Comment: @Muzzamil appium webdriverio with javascript

Comment: Please check solution and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture screenshot of an element with `webdriver io` as mentioned below

```
it('should save a screenshot of the browser view', function () {
    const elem = $('#someElem');
    elem.saveScreenshot('./some/path/elemScreenshot.png');
});
```

you can see more about in on official documentation of [webdriver-io](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/saveScreenshot.html)

Once you capture screenshot for both element then you can use Visual Regression service for `WebdriverIO` V5 called [wdio-image-comparison-service](https://github.com/wswebcreation/webdriver-image-comparison).

**Installation:**
Install this module locally with the following command to be used as a (dev-)dependency:

```
npm install --save-dev wdio-image-comparison-service
```

Instructions on how to install `WebdriverIO` can be found [here](https://webdriver.io/docs/clioptions.html).

**Usage:**

> wdio-image-comparison-service supports NodeJS 8 or higher

**Configuration:**
`wdio-image-comparison-service` is a service so it can be used as a normal service. You can set it up in your `wdio.conf.js` file with the following:

```
const { join } = require('path');

// wdio.conf.js
exports.config = {
    // ...
    // =====
    // Setup
    // =====
    services: [ 
        ['image-comparison', 
        // The options
        {
            // Some options, see the docs for more
            baselineFolder: join(process.cwd(), './tests/sauceLabsBaseline/'),
            formatImageName: '{tag}-{logName}-{width}x{height}',
            screenshotPath: join(process.cwd(), '.tmp/'),
            savePerInstance: true,
            autoSaveBaseline: true,
            blockOutStatusBar: true,
            blockOutToolBar: true,
            // ... more options
        }], 
    ],
    // ...
};
```

**Writing tests to compare screenshot of 2 elements:**

```
describe('Example', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
     browser.url('https://webdriver.io');
  });



  it('should save some screenshots', () => {

    // Save an element
    browser.saveElement($('#element-id'), 'firstButtonElement', { /* some options*/ });

  });



  it('should compare successful with a baseline', () => {

    // Check an element
    expect(browser.checkElement($('#element-id'), 'firstButtonElement', { /* some options*/ })).toEqual(0);

  });
});
```

Referenec: Please check all details about image comparison [here](https://webdriver.io/blog/2019/05/18/visual-regression-for-v5.html#writing-tests)

Comment: @testautomation I have to check for partial comparison of images.

Comment: Check here in bottom, https://webdriver.io/blog/2019/05/18/visual-regression-for-v5.html#writing-tests  "checkResult" will return mismatch percentage. so you can apply validation condition on mismatch percentage from function and expected percentage.